# WindowsForm - Como adicionar duas DataGridViewButtonCell em uma mesma cell?

Tags: c#, winforms, aplicação-desktop

É possível adicionar dois botões do tipo DataGridViewButtonCell na mesma célula em uma DataGridView? Pesquisei bastante e até agora não consegui encontrar nenhuma solução.

**Edit 1:**
Por exemplo, queria adicionar um botão [Manhã] e outro [Tarde] em uma mesma cell... Tentei adicionar uma panel, mas ele não aceita, porque o DataGridViewButtonCell não é do tipo Control.

**Edit 2:** 
Isso é o que consigo fazer atualmente...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Edit 3:** 
Bom, pensei em uma solução pra esse modelo de negócio. @RovannLinhalis deu a ideia de criar uma coluna a mais pra poder dividir direitinho entre MANHÃ e TARDE. O problema surge quando o usuário escolhe a opção de calendário QUINZENAL ou MENSAL, pois seriam geradas muitas colunas... Bom, ao invés de adicionar **n** colunas, adicionei linhas a mais, sendo elas divididas entre MANHÃ e TARDE. Ex:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém estou tendo algumas dificuldades em relação aos eventos do Windows Form. Nessa DataGridView estou criando um Rectangle e dando um DrawString nele no RowHeader, pra cada linha, onde aparece os números dos quartos (QUARTO: 22). Essa foi a solução que achei porque o DataGridView não possui o RowSpan.

Enfim, o problema aparece quando eu seleciono uma linha e logo em seguida eu seleciono outra. Parece que o Rectangle fica invisível... Ex: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código do evento:

```
reservaGrid_Grid.CellPainting += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (e.ColumnIndex == -1 && e.RowIndex > -1)
            {
                //exibe as datas em cima das colunas, desenhando de duas em duas linhas
                for (int i = 0; i < reservaGrid_Grid.RowCount; i += 2)
                {
                    string quarto = string.Format( "Quarto: {0}", Funcoes.String.FindStringAfterCharacter(reservaGrid_Grid.Rows[i].Tag.ToString(), '_') );

                    Rectangle retangulo     = reservaGrid_Grid.GetCellDisplayRectangle(-1, i, false);
                    //int largura           = reservaGrid_Grid.GetCellDisplayRectangle(-1, i + 1, true).Width;
                    retangulo.X             += 1;
                    retangulo.Y             += 1;
                    retangulo.Width         = retangulo.Width / 2 + 15;//largura do header
                    retangulo.Height        = retangulo.Height;//tamanho do header, preenche 2 linhas
                    StringFormat format     = new StringFormat();
                    format.Alignment        = StringAlignment.Center;
                    format.LineAlignment    = StringAlignment.Center;

                    //pinta o fundo do retangulo
                    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(
                        new SolidBrush(
                            reservaGrid_Grid.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor
                        ),
                        retangulo
                    );

                    //desenha a string no retangulo
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(
                        quarto,
                        new Font(reservaGrid_Grid.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Font.FontFamily, 13, FontStyle.Bold),
                        new SolidBrush(reservaGrid_Grid.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.ForeColor),
                        retangulo,
                        format
                    );
                }
            }
            //reservaGrid_Grid.Invalidate();
        };
```

Por que será?

Comment: Vai ter que criar uma coluna personalizada que tenha dois botões.

Comment: LiNQ, olhe meu editado. Não entendi muito bem a sua resposta, mas obrigado mesmo assim xD

Comment: Meu comentário continua o mesmo: ao invés de usar um objeto do tipo `DataGridViewButtonCell` para serem as células do DataGrid, vai ser necessário criar um próprio tipo que contenha dois botões. Aí você vai precisar implementar **todos** os métodos necessários para uma célula e alterar o DataGrid pra que use este tipo ao invés do `DataGridViewButtonCell`

Comment: acho mais fácil duplicar a coluna, ou manipular o evento da `cell` pra exibir um controle quando for clicada.

Comment: @RovannLinhalis eu já havia pensando em duplicar a coluna, mas tenho medo de ter de mudar muita coisa. O lance dessa grid seria avisar ao usuário se o quarto tá ocupado ou não, pintando os botões ou avisando de outra forma qualquer, e se não, permitir que o mesmo reserve clicando no botão desejado.

Comment: você pode usar uma imagem, e variar pelas imagens se está livre ou não... mas pensando em ter botões, e para cada, um comando diferente, acredito que a forma mais simples seria duplicar as colunas mesmo